# Spring Configuration заимпортить не весь Config класс

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Имеем:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "package1"
})
class Config1 {
}

package package1;
class Class1 {
}

package package1;
class Class2 {
}
```

таким образом, `Config1` сканит `Class1` и `Class2`

и все бы хорошо, но есть `Config2`

```
@Configuration
@Import(Config1.class)
class Config2 {

    @Bean
    public SomeClass someClass(Class1 class1) {
        return new SomeClass(class1);
    }
}
```

и проблема в том, что в этом `Config2` нужен `Class1`, но нельзя импортить его с `Class2`, т. к. `Class2` тянет за собой кучу всего ненужного. Вопрос в том, как заимпортить только 1 класс, который был просканен `Config2`

Answer (score 0):

Можно сконфигурировать Config1 так, чтобы он не включал Class2, и Config2, чтобы он включал только Class2.

Потом создать Config1and2, который импортирует 1й и 2й. В итоге у тебя будет 3 конфига на все случаи жизни.